# allow-control-allow-origin : * present in response, but it still shows error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, http-headers, cors

`allow-control-allow-origin : *` header is present in API Response, but browser is still showing the error. Network 403 Error.

***This is the sample Response header from API:***

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,X-CSRF-Token,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 870
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 17:56:46 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=6B492DE10EE
```

***Error in Firebug:***

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - https://xyz.....s"

 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xyz..... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

***Request - AngularJS***

```
var config = {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Apikey": "*************" 
                }
            }

            $http.post(URL, data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               //function
            })
```

Comment: The same as I have given...It is not Sample response..It is actual response header from Server.

Comment: It is the response from Server. It is common API server, we cannot change anything in server. Is there any possibilities to do the code in client side? Please advice.

Comment: I have added the request..Please check

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your server supports the `OPTIONS` verb and returns the proper CORS header when the client uses it - that's called the pre-flight request. Take a look at an example of a full CORS exchange between the client and the server [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

So the first step is the client to send a pre-flight request using the `OPTIONS` HTTP verb:

```
OPTIONS /canvas/73/source HTTP/1.1
Host: jsbin.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://jsconsole.com
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
```

Now your server should respond with the proper CORS headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
```

and that's it, you have established the handshake, now feel free to GET/POST anything you want:

```
GET /canvas/73/source HTTP/1.1
Host: jsbin.com
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

and you'll be granted with a success response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 977

...
```

You can also take a look at [this example](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working).

Comment: I didn't say that CORS headers should be added to GET and POST requests but to the OPTIONS request.